# PHP - WiFi Network Id and passphrase to hexadecimal key

Tags: php, wifi

To configure manually a WiFi network, I need the hexadecimal key.
In Ubuntu, I can obtain it with this comand:

```
wpa_passphrase network passphrase
```

And the result is:

```
network={
    ssid="network"
    #psk="passphrase"
    psk=72feda58f99812cd6a4a075047270e361e3ae18f8cb191eb8d55ac07f928a466
}
```

Then.. How can I obtain the psk with **PHP**?

**EDIT**: I do this:

```
<?php
$fp = fopen("data.txt", "w+");
    if(!$fp) die ("Errore nell'apertura del file");

exec("wpa_passphrase network passphrase",$output);

$conf = "";
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
    $conf .= $output[$i]."";
fwrite($fp,$conf);
fclose($fp);

exec("sudo cp data.txt /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf"); //this doesn't work!

echo "ok<br>".$conf
?>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean... Is your question about how to execute OS commands from PHP? (In that case this is most probably a duplicate.) If you are looking for a PHP lib doing this, it is off-topic on Stackoverflow. Could you elaborate? What have you tried?

Comment: I've did something.. Now I need to copy the data.txt file as /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf

Comment: Thanks, this is much better. This way probably someone will have idea what is your problem. My guess `sudo` requires authentication or the user of php is not one of the sudoers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved, this is the code:

```
<?php

$fp = fopen("data.txt", "w+");
if(!$fp) die ("Errore nell'apertura del file");

exec("wpa_passphrase network passphrase",$output);

$conf = "";
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
$conf .= $output[$i]."\n";
fwrite($fp,$conf);
fclose($fp);

exec("sudo cp data.txt /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf");

echo "1";

?>
```

But, to execute `sudo` command, I must add "www-data" user into sudoers file. I did this following [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21466325/3926054)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still interested in this: I solved this using plain PHP by reading through the source of [wpa_passphrase](http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/wpa_supplicant/html/wpa__passphrase_8c_source.html) and comparing the result to the [Wireshark PSK tool](https://www.wireshark.org/tools/wpa-psk.html).

```
function wpa_passphrase($ssid, $passphrase) {
    $bin = hash_pbkdf2('sha1', $passphrase, $ssid, 4096, 32, true);
    return bin2hex($bin);
}

$psk = wpa_passphrase('network', 'passphrase');
```

Requires PHP >= 5.5